# Is their an SQL function that can give me both a negative & positive value using the query below?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So effectively what im trying to do is display a value by counting all new users from the current month minus new users from last month then divide the increase by last months number then times by 100. This will get the percentage increase but never displays a negative number, I realise that using abs() converts negative numbers to positive, is their a function that would allow me to do this?

Thanks.

```
select round(abs
((select count(id) from users where 
month(created_at) = month(current_date())
and
YEAR(created_at) = year(current_date()))
-
(select count(id) from users where 
month(created_at) = month(current_date - interval 1 MONTH)
and
YEAR(created_at) = year(current_date - interval 1 MONTH)))
/
(select count(id) from users where 
month(created_at) = month(current_date())
and
YEAR(created_at) = year(current_date()))
*100, 0)
as abs_diff
from users
limit 1
;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the number of the new users of the current month with:

```
count(case when last_day(created_at) = last_day(current_date) then 1 end)
```

and the number of the new users of the previous month with:

```
count(case when last_day(created_at) = last_day(current_date - interval 1 month) then 1 end)
```

So divide these numbers and subtract 1 before you multiply by 100:

```
select
  100 * (
    count(case when last_day(created_at) = last_day(current_date) then 1 end) / 
    nullif(count(case when last_day(created_at) = last_day(current_date - interval 1 month) then 1 end), 0) 
    - 1
  ) abs_diff
from users
where date(created_at) > last_day(current_date - interval 2 month)
```

The function `nullif()` will return `null` in case the number of the new users of the previous month is `0` to avoid division by `0`.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=70ddd78e15219ae37996963b15cd535f).

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking something like this:

```
select ym.*,
       (this_month - last_month) * 100.0 / last_month
from (select year(created_at) as yyyy, month(created_at) as mm, count(*) as this_month,
             lag(count(*)) over (order by min(created_at)) as prev_month
      from users
      group by yyyy, mm
     ) ym;
```

Window functions are much simpler method to do month-over-month comparisons.

If you only want this for the current month, you can add:

```
order by yyyy desc, mm desc
limit 1
```